# R data frame manipulation pointers, conditional data manipulation

Tags: r, dataframe, conditional-statements

I ran into one of those "simple" data operations that seem needlessly annoying in R again. I have a large dataset and want to remove rows in a data frame based on the values of two columns.

What I need is to start dropping rows when y=z, and then stop dropping lines when the  value of z changes. The number of lines to be removed varies and I need to repeat this operation for all rows in the data frame.

[Original structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RmTEA.png),[Ideally result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dke9A.png)

I realize there are probably a million similar threads out there already, but I've already wasted enough time on trying to dig though basic tutorials. I would also be interested in general tips on packages that make data frame manipulations like this simpler in R, I use stuff like mutate and tidyr but is there anything that actually makes these operations less annoying?

Thanks

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Have you tried... base R? :) If you can make a small reproducible example perhaps we can have a whack at this.

Comment: If I had a small reproducible example I wouldn't need to ask :)

Comment: If the data is too large or has other problems the question is supposed to create an artificial test case showing the input using `dput` and also showing the expected output.  Please read the information at the top of the [tag:r] tag for guidance on asking questions and note the part about not using only images.

Comment: I gave you a clear explanation of the issue. But thanks for being helpful

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I found a dumb solution, using na.locf(zoo package) or ave(base) I created one ascending and one descending column with matching values in the rows that needed exclusion.

Thank you for your input, it seems data manipulation in R is just the worst

Comment: Please only use answers to post actual answers.  You can use comments or edit your question if you wish to add comments.

Comment: If this provides an answer to the question, it may help to provide actual code and explanation behind that code. This answer isn't as helpful as it can be.

Comment: This was the solution I actually used to solve the issue, so IMO this is an actual answer.

Answer (score 2):

**1)** Create test data DF and suppose we group the rows with a grouping variable g such that each group starts with a row for which y[i] == z[i] except possibly for the first group.  if y[i] or z[i] is NA then we shall regard them as unequal -- how to handle NA's was not defined so change this depending on what is wanted.

Now within each group get subgroups of contiguous rows for which y[i] equals y[j] or not where j is the first row of i's group and let eq0 be TRUE for each row of the first such subgroup within each group.

Also let eq1[i] be TRUE if the first row of its group, j, has eq[j] = TRUE.  This will be TRUE for every row except possibly for those in the first group.

With that setup we keep rows for which eq1[i] is FALSE or eq0[i] is FALSE.

This could be simplified if we knew that y[1] == z[1] so that the first group could be handled the same as the others and if there were no NA's.

No packages are used.

```
DF <- data.frame(y = mtcars$am, z = mtcars$vs) # test data

subset(DF, {
  eq <- y == z
  eq[is.na(eq)] <- FALSE
  g <- cumsum(eq)
  y[is.na(y)] <- Inf
  eq0 <- ave(y, g, FUN = function(x) cumsum(x != x[1]) == 0)
  eq1 <- ave(eq, g, FUN = function(x) x[1])
  !eq0 | !eq1
})
```

**2)** Using dplyr we can write it as

```
library(dplyr)

DF %>%
  mutate(eq = replace_na(y == z, FALSE)) %>%
  group_by(g = cumsum(eq)) %>%
  mutate(y1 = replace_na(y, Inf),
         eq0 = cumsum(y1 != first(y1)) == 0,
         eq1 = first(eq)) %>%
  dplyr::filter(!eq0 | !eq1) %>%
  ungroup %>%
  select(y, z)
```

Answer (score 0):

How about a `tidyverse` approach with `filter`? Here is test data where two variable are not equal to 4 at the same time:

```
library(tidyverse)
mtcars %>% filter(!(gear == 4 & carb == 4))
                     mpg cyl  disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
Datsun 710          22.8   4 108.0  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1
Hornet 4 Drive      21.4   6 258.0 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1
Hornet Sportabout   18.7   8 360.0 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0    3    2
Valiant             18.1   6 225.0 105 2.76 3.460 20.22  1  0    3    1
Duster 360          14.3   8 360.0 245 3.21 3.570 15.84  0  0    3    4
Merc 240D           24.4   4 146.7  62 3.69 3.190 20.00  1  0    4    2
```

Second thought, filter two variables that are equal:

```
mtcars %>% filter(!(vs == am))

                mpg cyl  disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
Mazda RX4      21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4
Mazda RX4 Wag  21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4
Hornet 4 Drive 21.4   6 258.0 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1
Valiant        18.1   6 225.0 105 2.76 3.460 20.22  1  0    3    1
```

Thanks to comments, after reading more careful I understand your problem like this, deleting rows 1:7

```
data(mtcars)
df <- mtcars[11:20,c("gear","carb")]
as_tibble(df)

# A tibble: 10 × 2
    gear  carb
   <dbl> <dbl>
 1     4     4
 2     3     3
 3     3     3
 4     3     3
 5     3     4
 6     3     4
 7     3     4
 8     4     1
 9     4     2
10     4     1
```

Comment: I think the OP wants a rule like: "delete rows starting from a row where y = z, and continue deleting until y changes`

Comment: The number of rows that needs to be deleted varies so row indexing aren't that useful :(